# Common factor in $2\sin(x)\cos(x) + \sin(x) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am stuck on part of a question :

The 1st line of work is :

$$2\sin(x)\cos(x) +\sin(x) = 0$$

The next line is :

$$\sin(x) \cdot (\sin(x)\cos(x) +1)$$

I see that $$\sin(x) \cdot 1 $$ gives $$\sin(x)$$

However how can $$\sin(x)\cdot \sin(x)\cos(x)$$ create $$2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

As there are $2$ lots of $\sin(x)$ , however still only $1$ lot of $\cos(x)$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the entire question :[image]

Comment: It cannot. It's just wrong.

Comment: Your second line is incorrect.  You are confusing $2\sin x$ with $\sin^2x$.  Your second line should read $\sin x(2\cos x + 1) = 0$.

Comment: The first line of what? The "next line" is wrong. Are you showing us your work, or something else? Help us help you - you've given us no context for us to help you.

Comment: $2\sin(x)\cos(x)+\sin(x)=\sin(x)\left(2\cos(x)+1\right)\neq \sin(x)\left(\sin(x)\cos(x)+1\right)$

Comment: I have added an image of the question in full for clarity. If you can, may someone please guide me on correcting a potential error in my notes ?

Comment: Now that your image of the question is added, we can see you've misquoted the second line of "work".  Rather than $\sin(x)(\sin(x)\cos(x) + 1) = 0$ it says $\sin(x)(1 + 2\cos(x))=0$.  Please edit your Question to correct the misquote, or simply accept that your Question was based in large part on this misunderstanding.

Comment: My sincere apologies !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $2\sin x\cos x+\sin x=0$ you get
$$
\sin x(2\cos x+1)=0
$$
because it's just like
$$
2ab+a=0
$$
that can be rewritten
$$
a(2b+1)=0
$$

By the way, there's a slicker way to solve $\sin2x+\sin x=0$. Rewrite it as
$$
\sin2x=-\sin x
$$
and recall that $-\sin x=\sin(x+\pi)$; therefore you have
$$
\sin 2x=\sin(x+\pi)
$$
that gives either
$$
2x=x+\pi+2k\pi \tag{1}
$$
or
$$
2x=\pi-(x+\pi)+2k\pi \tag{2}
$$
For the first solution set we get
$$
x=\pi+2k\pi \tag{1}
$$
and from the second one
$$
3x=2k\pi
$$
that is
$$
x=\frac{2}{3}k\pi \tag{2}
$$
If you want the solutions $-\pi\le x\le\pi$, you get, with $k=-1$ and $k=0$ in 1 and with $k=-1$, $k=0$ and $k=1$ from 2
$$
-\pi,\quad
-\frac{2}{3}\pi,\quad
0,\quad
\frac{2}{3}\pi,\quad
\pi
$$

Comment: Your answer has definately cleared things up for me ! very much appreciated. I am unfamiliar with −sinx=sin(x+π), therefore am unable to carry on with the second method, although it looks very interesting ! If you know of any online resources to explain this transition or if you had time to briefly explain that would be great !

Answer (score 4):

How can it? It cannot!

$$2\sin(x)\cos(x) + \sin(x) = 0$$ means
$$\sin(x)\left(2\cos(x) + 1\right) = 0$$

So you have the following cases (which are not coupled! They are two distinct possibilities)
$$
\begin{cases}
\sin(x)  = 0 \\\\
\cos(x)  = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Can you continue?

**Remarks, just trig pills**

- $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
- $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$
- $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$

more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

**And now the solutions! (Spoiler alert)**

$$\sin(x) = 0 \to x = n\pi ~~~~~~~ n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\cos(x) = -\frac{1}{2} \to x = \frac{2}{3}(3\pi n \pm \pi) ~~~~~~~ n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, perhaps I have copied the question down incorrectly. The edit contains an image of the question in its entirety, that may help.

Comment: I added the solutions, just in case!